# Java GSON TypeAdapterFactory:Parsing from String to Enum, when String value is not matched with Enums

Tags: java, android, enums, gson, retrofit

In my Android app I have ErrorResponse Class with all getter setter in which i am using Enum classs ErrorSubCode for subcode field.I am using gson to parse response coming from server.Till now it was ok as all error subcode coming from server was constant,now i have to support new error subcode which will come from server which is not static - it is like **download_error%count%** where **count** value can vary.

So Now if **download_error%count%** will come from server it is not gonna map with any enum as i cant define enum for this because value coming from server is not static.

```
        public class ErrorResponse {
            private ErrorSubCode subCode;
            private String userMessage;
        }

        public enum ErrorSubCode {
            SUBDOESNTEXIST,
            INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            SONGNOTFOUND,
            SONGEXPIRED,
            CATEGORYDOESNTEXIST,
            CONTENTEXPIRED
        }


//Custom class which implements TypeAdapterFactory.

public final class EnumSetAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        // return null, if the type is not an EnumSet
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final Class<T> rawType = (Class<T>) type.getRawType();
        Type fullType = type.getType();
        if (!EnumSet.class.isAssignableFrom(rawType)) {
            return null;
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        final Class enumClass = lookupEnumClass(fullType);
        if (enumClass == null) {
            // unable to lookup the enum class
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Unable to lookup the enum class for EnumSet: "
                            + type.toString());
        }

        final TypeAdapter<T> delegateAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this,
                type);

        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {

            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                delegateAdapter.write(out, value);
            }

            @Override
            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                // We know that T is an EnumSet, at the very least Gson will treat this like a set
                // Seems to use LinkedHashSet as of writing, we'll let it create one of those and then
                // copy it to an EnumSet.
                @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
                Set<Enum> set = (Set<Enum>) delegateAdapter.read(in);
                if (set.isEmpty()) {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    T copyOf = (T) EnumSet.noneOf(enumClass);
                    return copyOf;
                } else {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    T copyOf = (T) EnumSet.copyOf(set);
                    return copyOf;
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    protected Class lookupEnumClass(Type fullType) {
        if (fullType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
            ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) fullType;
            return (Class) parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

//Below is the code how I am parsing response coming from server using gson.

```
    String json = getBodyString(r);
                                GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder()
                                        .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
                                gsonBuilder
                                        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new LowercaseEnumTypeAdapterFactory(
                                                true));
                                gsonBuilder
                                        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new EnumSetAdapterFactory());
                                Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
                                errorResponse = gson.fromJson(json, ErrorResponse.class);
```

Now what can i do in case of if **download_error%count%** will come from server as subCode? 
I want something like if it doesnt match with any enum value it gives me exact string coming from server in any other field or somebody can tell me the way how can i support this new **download_error%count%** error code in existing code.

As asked Json Response would be

{
   "sub_code": "DOWNLOADS_OVERLIMIT%value%",
   "usermessage": "Any Message"
}

Comment: Can you post the json response ?

Comment: As asked I have edited with Json response which i want to parse. But problem is value can vary in subcode.